# Why is Rivets.js not working on mobile?

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile, npm, rivets.js

I have a webapp that I am converting to a mobile app using Cordova. The only thing I can't seem to get working is `rivets.js`. I have tried on an Android device, iOS device and in a browser on my computer and all I see throughout the pages are `{}` containing pointers to the data we want to show but not the actual data. I'm not sure if I'm missing some configuration or dependency or if rivets is knows to not work on mobile? As far as I know there aren't any. Anyone have an idea on what I may be missing or what may be causing this?

The webapp is run through `electron` to create a desktop app that run on a Windows PC and that desktop app works without any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the issue was the code that actually bundled the data to the UI and some of the data itself was not included in the browserify bundle. Once I added those js files to the bundle it worked like a charm.